# Add class after loading an image jquery

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have the following code to add a class after loading an image:

```
$('.single aside img').attr('src', 'assets/img/ajax-loader.gif');

$('.single aside img').attr('src', url).load(function () {  
    $('.single aside img').addClass('loaded');
});
```

But it's not working, it adds the class before it loads. Any ideas?

Comment: You are missing a quote... Is that just a copy paste mistake or is this your actual code?

Comment: The missing quotes are obviously only in the question. "it adds the class before it loads" - that wouldn't happen if there were syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing I see wrong with your code is that in your callback function, you are using the same selector that you used originally.

What you'll want to do is reference the actual element that was loaded. For this you can use the `$(this)` keyword.

```
$('.single aside img').attr('src', url).load(function () {  
  $(this).addClass('loaded');
});

// another interpretation of the code...
// var loaded = 'loadedClass';
// $('.single aside img').attr('src', url).load(function () {  
//   $(this).addClass(loaded);
// });
```

There was also a missing quote in your code, but I suspect that was just a copy paste error so I'm ignoring it.

Comment: thanks, but that still adds the class before it loads for some reason.

Comment: @use - the callback of the load function is supposed to only fire once the element has loaded. Are you sure there is no other code adding the class hiding somewhere?

Comment: well I do have this before it which just shows a loader.gif before the main image loads: ...I'll add it to the original post see above.

Answer (score 0):

The `load` method is for fetching data from server (Ajax calls) as you can see here: http://api.jquery.com/load/. You must bind a `load` event to your image.

```
var loaded = 'loadedClass';
$('.single aside img').attr('src', url).bind('load', function () {
    $(this).addClass(loaded);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this code at the end of `<body>`

(before `</body>`)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const class_name_to_add="loaded";
    
    let pending_images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    pending_images.forEach((img) => {
      let isLoaded = img.complete && img.naturalHeight !== 0;
      if (isLoaded) {
        img.classList.add(class_name_to_add);
      } else {
        img.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
          img.classList.add(class_name_to_add);
        });
      }
    });                                   
</script>
```

**do not** put this code in `DOMContentLoaded` or `$(document).ready()`